# Json error org.json.JSONException: No value for

Tags: android, json

it gives me the error log : " org.json.JSONException: No value for tableData"

```
try {
    JSONObject  mainJson22 = new JSONObject(reply);

    JSONObject jsonResult = mainJson22.getJSONObject("UserListByBusinessAreaContextResult");
    JSONArray jsonArray22 = jsonResult.getJSONArray("tableData");

// JSONArray jsonArray22 = mainJson22.getJSONArray("UserListByBusinessAreaContextResult"); // JSONArray jsonArray22 = jsonResult.getJSONArray("tableData"); Log.i("mainjson234","" + jsonArray22);


    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < jsonArray22.length(); i2++) {

       JSONObject objJson22 = jsonArray22.getJSONObject(i2);
```

the error is on line : `"JSONArray jsonArray22 = jsonResult.getJSONArray("tableData");"

heres the json:

```
{
    "UserListByBusinessAreaContextResult": "{\"tableData\":[{\"UserID\":30,\"Username\":\"Teste\",\"Name\":\"Teste\"}]}"
}
```

Comment: The `UserListByBusinessAreaContextResult` value is JSON i.e. your JSON is double encoded.

Comment: Did you generate the json?

Comment: No, I receive the json from a wcf service

Comment: Well since `UserListByBusinessAreaContextResult ` is json you'll have to decode it as well to get to the array inside it.

Comment: Look at gson to do deserialization makes life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The object `UserListByBusinessAreaContextResult` contains a string. This string is:

```
"{\"tableData\":[{\"UserID\":30,\"Username\":\"Teste\",\"Name\":\"Teste\"}]}"
```

Do you notice the quotes? The problem is, that your WCF service returns a JSON string, not an object. So either you will have to change the WCF service to deliver an object instead, or parse that string again. Like this (not tested):

```
JSONObject  mainJson22 = new JSONObject(reply);
JSONObject tableData = new JSONObject(
        mainJson22.getString("UserListByBusinessAreaContextResult"));
```